# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, web, compiler-errors

[I want a solution for this error please and I installed npm express-session by the way

const session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
secret: 'secret-key',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false,
}));

and error is

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')
at Object. (D:\chrome downloads\network\network\myapp\app.js:42:5)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96Pep.png)

Comment: app.use(session({ secret: 'secret-key', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false, }));
-- can u please help me to understand, how are u mounting middleware , because to mount middleware we are using method app.use(path, middlewareFunction).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `app`. You need to define it using `const app = express()`.

Comment: it worked thank you very much I appreciated